# Pivot Creation using VBA with specific sheet name

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

Trying to create a pivot using the below code, but it gets error.

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$EX$45741"), , xlYes).Name _

    = "Table1"

  Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Rec Coverage Area]]").Select



  PivotSheetName = "Pivot Cash " + Format(Date, "MM DD YYYY")

  Sheets.Add.Name = PivotSheetName





  ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _

    "Table1", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable TableDestination _

    :=PivotSheetName & "!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable20", DefaultVersion:= _

    xlPivotTableVersion14
```

The error is related with the code:

> ```
> TableDestination _
>
>         :=PivotSheetName & "!R3C1",
> ```

Also, the wait I am creating table in the first line, creates only for a specific range:`Range("$A$1:$EX$45741")`

But the tabke can be dynamic can have more cols/rows than that. How can I get the code which will create the range as per row/col. (Column A cells will be having some value so we can get the last row of column A & Row 1 will be having some value so we can get the last column of Row 1.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the precise range definition (referring columns 1 and range 1, as you said):

```
Sub RangeDefinition()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long, rng As Range
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your needed sheet
   lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
   lastCol = sh.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
   Set rng = sh.Range(sh.Range("A1"), sh.Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
    Debug.Print rng.Address 'in order to check if it returns what you need...
End Sub
```

Please, try fully defining your variables. `ActiveSheet` may bring problems if, by mistake your active sheet is different. In my code I used `ActiveSheet` only for test purpose, recommending to use your (real) sheet name.

`UsedRange` can work if the sheet has just been created and you did not make any format modifications below the existing data...
In this way, the range margins are calculated.

For the other issue, firstly try:
`TableDestination:=PivotSheetName & "!R3C1",`

instead of
`TableDestination _`

```
    `:=PivotSheetName & "!R3C1",`
```

At least, delete the intermediary empty row. Such a way works only for consecutive rows.

Answer (score 0):

probably you can try  instead

```vb
Range("a1").CurrentRegion
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it